# express static: Conflict when folder-name equals html-page-name

Tags: node.js, express

I serve static content via

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../Frontend'),{index:"index.html",extensions:['html']}));
```

In the folder **/Frontend** is a file with **filename: projects.html** and a folder with the **foldername: projects**. This constellation is conflicting and not working.

How can I serve projects.html on www.example.com/projects and the html-files inside the folder on www.example.com/projects/xyz?
(At the moment www.example.com/projects/xyz works and www.example.com/projects returns a 404. Furthermore there is a 301 redirect from /projects to /projects/)

Comment: Try this:

`app.use('/projects', express.static('../Frontend'))` and in ../Frontend/projects place an index.html which is your projects.html

Comment: At the moment www.example.com/projects/xyz works and www.example.com/projects returns a 404. Furthermore there is a 301 redirect from /projects to /projects/ (I added this info also to the question above)

Comment: If you just have one route `/projects` that doesn't work correctly, you can make one custom route placed before `express.static()` and manually serve the desired file for that specific route and let `express.static()` handle the ones that it works fine for.  You have created a conflict in `express.static()` with your structure where its ambigious whether you want `/projects` to serve the `index.html` from within that directory or whethe ryou want it to serve `projects.html` from the automatic adding of `.html` extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a solution (Thank you all for the comments you posted)

Before:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../Frontend'),{index:"index.html",extensions:['html']}));
```

After (The order is relevant):

```
app.use('/projects', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../Frontend/projects.html')));  
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../Frontend'),{index:"index.html",extensions:['html']}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on my comment, I would suggest a variation of what you used:

```
app.get('/projects', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../Frontend/projects.html'));
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../Frontend'),{index:"index.html",extensions:['html']}));
```

This will be more efficient because the first route will only match `/projects`, not everything else that starts with `/projects`.